# perldoc perllocal shows other modules as installed

Tags: perl, perldoc

I did change the install-dir for cpan modules and added this directory to the PERL5LIB so that i can use the modules in my scripts.

I wanted an overview of the modules i installed, but when i do 'perldoc perllocal' i get listed LWP::MediaTypes, Encode::Locale, IO::HTML and HTTP::Date, although i only installed HTTP:Request.

I know that i've installed more modules due to dependencies, but why is HTTP:Request not listed and also no LWP::UserAgent although i can use it in my scripts?

Thanks